# ElasticSearch Bulk with ingest plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the Attachment Processor [Attachment Processor](http://Using%20the%20Attachment%20Processor%20in%20a%20PipelineeditTable%201.%20Attachment%20options) in a Pipeline.

All work fine, but i wanted to do multiple post, then I tried to used [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).
Bulk work fine too, but I can't find how to send the url parameter "pipeline=attachment".

this put works :

```
POST testindex/type1/1?pipeline=attachment
{
  "data": "Y291Y291",
  "name" : "Marc",
  "age" : 23
}
```

this bulk works :

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "testindex", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "name" : "jean", "age" : 22 }
```

But how can I index Marc with his data field in bulk to be understood by the pipeline plugin?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910185/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Val comment, I did that and it work fine:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "testindex", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2", "pipeline": "attachment"} } }
{"data": "Y291Y291", "name" : "jean", "age" : 22}
```