# In Elasticsearch 5+, is there any way to perform a bulk reindex and specify a pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to be able to perform bulk reindex requests and also specify a pipeline. The pipeline blanks out some fields and adds another indicating that this action has been taken. Due to security concerns, scripting is not an option.

The destination indices will only contain document such that they have gone through the pipeline.

I know that there's no way to do this with the Java client (one can bulk reindex but can't specify a pipeline), but what about in the REST API?

e.g. to perform the reindexes at the bottom here in bulk (the assumption is that there will be millions of values for `message_id` that will be provided from elsewhere):

```
#Create some data:
POST /mytestindex/message
{
  "message_id": "123-456-789",
  "body": "this is some text"
}

POST /mytestindex/message
{
  "message_id": "234-567-890",
  "body": "this is also some text"
}

#Create a pipeline to blank out the body field 
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/my-test-pipeline
{
  "description": "my test pipeline",
  "processors": [{
    "set": {
      "field": "body",
      "value": ""
    }
  }]
}

#reindex by message_id:
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "mytestindex",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "message_id": "123-456-789"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "mytestindex_new",
    "pipeline": "my-test-pipeline"
  }
}

POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "mytestindex",
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "message_id": "234-567-890"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "mytestindex_new",
    "pipeline": "my-test-pipeline"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that using the REST API, basically like this

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest",
    "pipeline": "some_ingest_pipeline"   <-- specify your pipeline here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to do that in bulk?

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your question, i.e. I've read "reindex" and not "bulk". Here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909936/elastic-search-bulk-api-pipeline-and-geo-ip/41910185#41910185

Comment: That doesn't appear to address reindexing

Comment: Then I don't get what you mean by bulk reindex... the Reindex API that is in my answer does it in bulk already.

Comment: Any news here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was asking the wrong question - I was looking for a way to reindex using the bulk API, but it appears that the API does not yet support bulk api reindexing with specifying a pipeline.